# Positioning The Barometer Instruction Counter In Shell Sort

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I made a shell sort function in C++ and I was trying to calculate the most instruction or comparison performed (Big-O notation) in any case, but I was confused about where to put the counter in the function, since the Big-O notation is a little weird compared to other sorting algorithms. Like in merge sort and selection sort, it is in all cases n*log(base 2)n and n^2, respectively. I just need to know whether I put the barometer counter in the right place or not. Here is my code:

```
template <class T>
int ShellSort(T arr[], int n)
{
    int counter = 0;

    for (int gap = n / 2; gap > 0; gap /= 2)
    {

        for (int i = gap; i < n; i += 1)
        {
            ++counter;                                                    // - Add a counter here in case the third loop's case was not met at the beginning.
            T temp = arr[i];                                              // - Store the picked ith value for comparison. 

            int j;
            for (j = i; j >= gap && arr[j - gap] > temp; j -= gap) {
                ++counter;                                                // - The main counter position.
                arr[j] = arr[j - gap];                                    // - Assign the value at j to j - gap.
            }


            arr[j] = temp;                                                // - Assign whatever in temp to the last jth value to finish the swap. 
        }
    }

    return counter;
}
```

Comment: [Looks good to me?](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/373d48962a263416)

Comment: Are you sure? Because whenever you count the number of instructions in an algorithm, you focus on the most inner loop only, but my most inner loop got a second condition (arr[j - gap] > temp) which can even prevent the counter from counting at all, so I added the one before. I don't know if that is right or wrong.